# Why is the sitemap not Fetch in search console?

Tags: search, seo, sitemap, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I have a site that is written with php and now when I try to connect the site map to the search console, it gives a coudnt fetch error. The site is already WordPress and the site map itself has no problem.
[site address](https://mandegar.co.com/)
[site map](https://mandegar.co.com/sitemap.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XML sitemap of your website upload the file in Search Console

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Google's crawlers do not access URLs correctly
you should use a dynamic sitemap.